# Power Failures and Torrent Download

Tags: download, bittorrent, utorrent, file-download

I am downloading a large torrent. I had 2 power failures during the download. Will this affect the file integrity? The torrent client did not seem to run a check once I booted up after power was restored. ETA 24 Hours

Comment: It shouldn't, and at worst only affect a few chunks from around the time that you had the power failure. In your shoes, I'd let the torrent complete, and force a recheck to be sure, but torrents are fairly resilient to power failures and other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the torrent client, some will do a verification on start/restart of the download.  Otherwise the client will perform the verification at the end of the download.  Some clients provide a way to force a re-check.

Generally though, this is not something that needs to be worried about....as each chunk downloaded from a peer should be verified before it is written to disk...essentially making the download crash-proof.

While downloading a high traffic torrent (lots of seeds), there will be invalid chunks downloaded all the time, the client will discard them and re-download those chunks from the same peers (as the invalid chunk could be due to network issues) or another peer...most clients will ban a bad peer after x number of bad chunk downloads.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will let the DL finish. Just did not want to waste my cap! Cheers